# Failed to compile. ./src/scss/style.scss ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 39

Tags: reactjs, sass, web-deployment, netlify

I'm trying to run  a build to react app so I can deploy it to Netlify, however each time I'm getting this error and I don't know where it comes from or how can I solve it, I think the issue comes from the library it self because I comment the importing of its SCSS files it complies fine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSgOp.png)

please advise me what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Please, include the relevant section of the file in question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any updates? I have the same problem.